# How do I update values without refreshing the page on my Flask project?

Tags: python, flask

I have a website that shows the prices of items in a video game.

Currently, I have an "auto-refresh" script that refreshes the page every 5 seconds, but it is a bit annoying as every time you search for a product, it removes your search because the page refreshes.

I would like to update the numbers in my table without refreshing the page for the user. I read something about 'updating the DOM', in javascript but didn't get it.

Here is the link to my website: http://xeltool.com/

And here is my python code:

```
@app.route('/bprices', methods=['GET'])
def bPrices():
    f = requests.get(
        'https://api.hypixel.net/skyblock/bazaar?key=[cannot show]').json()

    products = [
        {
            "id": product["product_id"],
            "sell_price": product["sell_summary"][:1],
            "buy_price": product["buy_summary"][:1],
            "sell_volume": product["quick_status"]["sellVolume"],
            "buy_volume": product["quick_status"]["buyVolume"],
        }
        for product in f["products"].values()
    ]
    return render_template("bprices.html", products=products)
```

And here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="search_div">
    <input
      type="text"
      onkeyup="myFunction()"
      id="myInput"
      title="Type in a product"
      class="search-box"
      placeholder="Search for a product..."
    />
    <button class="search-btn"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
  </div>

  <table
    id="myTable"
    class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm table-dark sortable"
    cellspacing="0"
  >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th aria-label="Product Name" data-balloon-pos="up">Product</th>
        <th aria-label="Product's buy price" data-balloon-pos="up">
          Buy Price
        </th>
        <th aria-label="Product's sell price" data-balloon-pos="up">
          Sell Price
        </th>
        <th aria-label="Product's buy volume" data-balloon-pos="up">
          Buy Volume
        </th>
        <th aria-label="Product's sell volume" data-balloon-pos="up">
          Sell Volume
        </th>
        <th>
          Margin
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for product in products %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ product.id|replace("_", ' ')|lower()|title() }}</td>
        {% for buy in product.buy_price %}
        <td>{{ buy.pricePerUnit }}</td>
        {% for sell in product.sell_price %}
        <td>{{ sell.pricePerUnit }}</td>

        <td>{{ product.buy_volume| numberFormat }}</td>
        <td>{{ product.sell_volume| numberFormat }}</td>
        {% set margin = buy.pricePerUnit - sell.pricePerUnit%} {% set marginPer
        = margin/buy.pricePerUnit * 100%}
        <td
          aria-label="{{ marginPer|round(1, 'floor') }} % "
          data-balloon-pos="right"
        >
          {{ margin|round(1, 'floor')}}
        </td>
        {% endfor %}{% endfor %}
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

If you NEED the API to test this out, I can provide a link to it :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have 3 options:

- AJAX - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp
- SSE - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events
- Websocket - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/WebSockets

I think the best option in your case is SSE since the server knows that the price was changed so it can push it to the clients.

Comment: so I have to send over all the variables from flask to JS?

Comment: actually, it looks like flask has a module named sse. Can be seen here https://flask-sse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: correct - there is a support for SSE. Its important you will understand why SSE is the best option for you.

Comment: yeah I don't really udnerstand, redis? What do I need to do with redis?

Comment: I Will read a bit on "SSE", found a really interesting thread about AJAX so I will take a good look at that as well, but thanks for the help. I will do some reading and hopefully figure it out!

Comment: see https://medium.com/code-zen/python-generator-and-html-server-sent-events-3cdf14140e56

Answer (score 3):

Use AJAX to ask for new prices. The API will return the values and then in the JS code just change the previous price to the new price.

AJAX will definitely help.

Have a look at the simple tutorial here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp.

Comment: yes, thats what I have read as well. But not really sure how it would work with flask? I mean I am getting the API information on flask, how would AJAX update it?

Comment: ajax will get the data in json format. Then with Javascript you will find place where you want to put new data and will put it in. F.e. with `document.getElementById("yourElementID").innerText = "text taken from json";` and this will asign new content into targeted html element.